# Оптимизация хранения данных в БД

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Существует проект. В текущем виде, для каждого клиента создается по 3 таблицы в БД MySql, (условно, таблица с конфигурацией пользователя, таблица с сообщениями итп). В связи с особенностями проекта, для каждого отдельно взятого клиента структура соответствующих ему таблиц может быть различной, однако все же соответствует одному из нескольких типов.

Число клиентов постоянно увеличивается, в связи с этим, собственно, вопросы:

1) Насколько наличие большого количества таблиц в БД влияет на производительность и надежность хранения данных?

2) Стоит ли оставить все в том виде, что есть, или нужно переделать логику хранения и подогнать под фиксированное количество таблиц, тем самым во много раз увеличив число записей в этих самых таблицах. (Если проще: Что лучше - много таблиц с небольшим количеством записей или пара таблиц с огромным количеством записей)

3) Каковы ограничения (и существуют ли они) по количеству записей в одной таблице и по количеству таблиц в БД.

4) Какой тип таблиц выбирать? (InnoDB/MyISAM)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Насколько наличие большого количества таблиц в БД влияет на производительность и надежность хранения данных?

*-- Кол-во таблиц и количество записей не лимитируются. Но поддерживать большое кол-во сложнее, особенно если в будущем потребуется правка касающаяся всех клиентов.*

2) Стоит ли оставить все в том виде, что есть, или нужно переделать логику хранения и подогнать под фиксированное количество таблиц, тем самым во много раз увеличив число записей в этих самых таблицах. (Если проще: Что лучше - много таблиц с небольшим количеством записей или пара таблиц с огромным количеством записей)

*-- Создайте три таблицы со стандартными данными и еще таблицу с клиентами, в первых трех используйте ID из таблицы клиентов и это решит все проблемы.*

3) Каковы ограничения (и существуют ли они) по количеству записей в одной таблице и по количеству таблиц в БД.

*-- Кол-во таблиц и количество записей не лимитируются.*

4) Какой тип таблиц выбирать? (InnoDB/MyISAM)

*-- При использовании больших таблиц лучше использовать InnoDB в интернете много статей сравнения видов.*